# FIWARE- Quantumleap | Error getting Historical Data (422)

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to use echart widget for wirecloud display. The logic of the wiring is:
quantumleapsource -->quantumleap 2 echart --> echart.

I keeping the two errors below:

```
1. Error getting Historical Data (422): {"description":"The parameter value '1637496000000' for parameter **fromDate** or **toDate** is not valid.","error":"<class 'exceptions.exceptions.InvalidParameterValue'>"}

2. Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error
```

I have tried different date formats like: 2021-11-21T12:00:00Z , 2021-11-21T16:00:44.600+00:00 , 2021-11-16T16:00:44.600. But the error persists.
What could be wrong? Or How can use echart in wirecloud?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the historical data(422) has already been dealt with in https://github.com/Ficodes/quantumleap-source-operator/pull/19
The subscription error is solved by ensuring the context broker and NGSI proxy is up and running. Also key in the correct IP addresses.